# Use existing Method instead of new Parameter

Tags: java

I'm trying to finish this project and I can't figure how to use my existing method in my other method. I want to get rid of `VOWELS`, which is defined as a field the class, and I just want to use the method `isVowel` which returns a `boolean` after you type in a `Char`.

This is what I have:

```
public class StringAndIO {

    private static Scanner v;
    static final String VOWELS = "AaEeIiOoUuÄäÖöÜü";

    public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e' || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'I' || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u'
            || c == 'U' || c == 'ä' || c == 'Ä' || c == 'ö' || c == 'Ö' || c == 'ü' || c == 'Ü') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String toPigLatin(String text) {
        String ret = "";
        String vowelbuf = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
            char x = text.charAt(i);
            if (VOWELS.indexOf(x) != -1) {
                vowelbuf += x;
            } else {
                if (vowelbuf.length() > 0) {
                    ret += vowelbuf + "b" + vowelbuf + x;
                    vowelbuf = "";
                } else {
                    ret += x;
                }
            }
        }
        if (vowelbuf.length() > 0) {
            ret += vowelbuf + "b" + vowelbuf;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * only there for testing purpose
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        v = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Char!");
        char c = v.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(isVowel(c));
        String s = "Meine Mutter ißt gerne Fisch";
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(toPigLatin(s));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take your time to make the code readable for us. Also that's not JavaScript.

Comment: why tagged "JavaScript"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is how to use your `isVowel(x)` method inside the other method

```
 public static String toPigLatin(String text) {


    String ret = "";
    String vowelbuf = "";


    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
        char x = text.charAt(i);
        if (isVowel(x)) {
            vowelbuf += x;
        } else {
            if (vowelbuf.length() > 0) {
                ret += vowelbuf + "b" + vowelbuf + x;
                vowelbuf = "";
            } else {
                ret += x;
            }
        }
    }
    if (vowelbuf.length() > 0) {
        ret += vowelbuf + "b" + vowelbuf;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Tank you very much !